# range of closed subset via quotient map

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, inequality, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed vector space. Let $V \subset X$ be a closed subspace, and let
$W \subset X$ be a finite-dimensional subspace.

Suppose $V \cap W = \{0\}$ and that there exists a $C \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $\lVert x \rVert + \lVert y \rVert ≤ C \lVert x − y \rVert$ for all $x \in V , y \in W$.

Let $q : X \rightarrow X/W$ be the quotient map.

I would like to show that $q(V)$ is closed. I tried to use a sequence in order to show that $q(V)$ is sequentially closed but it must not be the right approach because this way, I never needed to use the inequality that is given above, which is weird.

Does anyone have an idea ? Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: The condition is not weird. It tells that if $x_n\in V$ and $y_n\in W$ satisfy $x_n-y_n\to 0$ then $x_n\to 0$ and $y_n\to 0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: In the question, "which is weird" refers to never needing to use the inequality, not to the inequality.

Comment: @joriki You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that for $x_n\in V$ we have $[x_n]\in X/W$ tends to $[x].$ Then $[x_n-x]\to 0.$ Hence for every $k$ there is $n_k$ such that
$$\|[x_{n_k}-x]\|<{1\over k}$$ By definition of the norm in $X/W$ there exists $w_{n_k}\in W$ such that
$$\|x_{n_k}-w_{n_k}-x\|<{2\over k}\quad (*)$$
Thus $$\|(x_{n_k}-w_{n_k})-(x_{n_l}-w_{n_l})\|\le {2\over k}+{2\over l}$$ This implies $$\|w_{n_k}-w_{n_l}\|\le C\left ({2\over k}+{2\over l}\right )$$
Hence the sequence $w_{n_k}$ is convergent, say to $w.$ We have used the fact that a finite dimensional normed space is always complete. The condition $(*)$ implies that $x_{n_k}\to w+x.$ As $V$ is closed we get $w+x\in V.$ Thus $[x]\in q(V),$ which completes the proof.

Comment: This is very clear, thank you very much !