# Normed Space Bound on Sum of Norms

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

I saw this post [range of closed subset via quotient map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4622356/range-of-closed-subset-via-quotient-map) which reminded me of a problem I was given, which I couldn't solve.

Let $X$ be a normed vector space, $V \subseteq X$ a closed subspace, $W \subseteq X$ a finite-dimensional subspace and suppose that $V \cap W = \{0\}$. Prove that there exists a constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\forall v \in V  \forall w \in W: \quad \lVert v\rVert + \lVert w\rVert \leq C \lVert v - w \rVert. $$

I tried to do it by contradiction by assuming there was a sequence $(v_n,w_n) \in V \times W$ such that $$\lVert v_n \rVert + \lVert w_n \rVert > n \lVert v_n - w_n \rVert$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ which didn't lead me anywhere. Where could one use the fact that $W$ is finite-dimensional?

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the strict inequality sign, it follows $\|v_n\|+\|w_n\|>0$. You can divide the inequality by $\|v_n\|+\|w_n\|$. So you rescale the sequences to achieve
$$
1 = \|v_n\|+\|w_n\| > n \|v_n-w_n\|.
$$
So $(w_n)$ is a bounded sequence in a finite-dimensional space... In addition, $\|v_n -w_n\|\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess we can descend to a subsequence $(w_{n_k})$ converging to say $w \in W$ because $W$ is finite-dimensional. Now using $\|v_n -w_n\|\to 0$ we get that $(v_{n_k})$ also converges to $w$ and thus $w=0$ because $V$ is closed, so $w \in V$ and $V \cap W = \{0\}$. This would then contradict $1 = \|v_{n_k}\| + \|w_{n_k}\|$ by continuity of the norm... right?